# Schedulable batch class to insert a list then update a related parent list

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I am trying to create a scheduled batch class to query existing records for a custom object, add it to a list then insert the list of records for the same custom object, then update a custom field for a list belonging to the parent object, via a lookup field . The `GF__c` is the child object, and the Opportunity is the parent object.  when I run it, it does create the new list of child records,  but I am getting an error regarding the parent list:

> Duplicate id in List::...

and the custom field of the parent isn't getting updated.  I've posted my code below, any assistance is appreciated.

```
public class GF__cBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {
    public GF__cBatch() {}
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(this, 60);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Opportunity_Name__c, Forecast_Month_Year_Current_Month_Year__c FROM GF__c WHERE Forecast_Month_Year_Current_Month_Year__c=true]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
        list<GF__c> gfList = new list<GF__c>();
        list<Opportunity> OppList = new list<Opportunity>();
        datetime myDateTime = datetime.now();        
        For(Sobject s :scope){
            GF__c GF = (GF__c) s;           
            gfList.add(new GF__c(                
                Opportunity_Name__c = GF.Opportunity_Name__c                                               
            ));
            Opplist = [SELECT Id, Forecast_Month_Year__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :GF.Opportunity_Name__c];            
            OppList.add(new Opportunity(
                Id = GF.Opportunity_Name__c,                
                Forecast_Month_Year__c = myDateTime.format('MMMM, YYYY')
            ));   
        }        
        try{
            insert gfList;            
            if(OppList.size() > 0){          
                update OppList;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception E){
            system.debug('Error is: ' + E.getMessage());
        }                
    }    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        system.debug('FORECAST CREATE JOB IS FINISHED');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the formatting tools (`{}` button or Ctrl-K) to make sure your code gets rendered appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to want to take the query out of the loop, too, or larger batches (>100) will automatically fail.

Comment: Please check this help article, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257270&language=en_US&type=1

Answer (score 2):

You're going to run into trouble here when you're processing more than one `GF__c` record with the same Opportunity as parent. The reason that's the case is that your code accumulates a `List<Opportunity>` to update, with one entry for each `GF__c`.

As a result, if you have N `GF__c` records with the same Opportunity, you'll have N Opportunities in the update list with the same Id. Salesforce doesn't allow that in a single DML operation.

The typical idiom is to use a `Map<Id, Opportunity>`, where you set each Opportunity needing to be updated in the map under its Id:

```
// We found an Opportunity with Id myId needing to be updated
myMap.put(myId, new Opportunity(Id = myId, ANOTHER_FIELD = VALUE, ...)
```

and then do

```
update myMap.values();
```

This ensures they're deduplicated appropriately, because Maps are inherently one-to-one mappings. Your code can also check whether it's already looked at a child record for that Opportunity by simply looking at whether `myMap.containsKey(someOpportunityId)`. If, for example, you need to populate the largest value of a field on the child object, you could then pull the Opportunity instance back out of the Map and run some logic to decide *which child object value* you wanted to populate.

Additionally, your batch has a bulkification issue, which I assume is why you set the scope size to 60. You need to move the Opportunity query outside the loop. However, if you adopt the Map-based pattern above, it looks to me like you don't need to query at all, since you're constructing new sObject instances.

Comment: Forgive my lack of experience, but can you provide an example of what you mean? I don't fully understand.

Comment: I've extended my answer a little bit - I hope this makes it a little more clear.